# Retrofit API calls are not synchronous in Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, google-maps-android-api-2, java-threads

I am getting location of the user in the background service and putting it in local database and I am checking if any connection is available I've to pass this data to the server using API. For API I am using `retrofit2 2.9.0` but my API calls are going in an asynchronous way I tried many things run the code in a synchronous way but failed.

I also tried to use threads but still the data has been sent in an asynchroniaed way. Is there any way to do so in a synchronized way or any suggestion for the solution.

Here is the part of code which is causing much issues

```
               DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(BackgroundServices.this);

               ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                
                //IF MY NETWORK IS AVAILABLE
                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    // READ THE SQLITE DATABASE
                    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                            "SELECT * FROM " + Constants.READINGS_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                                    + Constants.READINGS_STATUS + "=?",
                            new String[]{
                                    String.valueOf(Constants.STATUS_NOT_UPLOADED)
                            }
                    );
                    
                    // IF TABLE SEQUENCES ARE CHANGED THEN THIS WILL GET THE INDEX ACCORDING TO THE CHANGED INDEXES
                    int locationReadingsID = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_ID);
                    int locationReadingsLat = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_LAT);
                    int locationReadingsLon = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_LON);
                    int locationReadingsTimestamp = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_TIMESTAMP);
                    int locationReadingsAltitude = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_ALTITUDE);
                    int locationReadingsSpeed = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_SPEED);
                    int locationReadingsBearing = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_BEARING);
                    int locationReadingsAccuracy = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_ACCURACY);
                    int locationReadingsTemp = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_TEMP);
                    int locationReadingsFeelsLike = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_FEELS_LIKE);
                    int locationReadingsTempMax = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_TEMP_MAX);
                    int locationReadingsTempMin = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_TEMP_MIN);
                    int locationReadingsPressure = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_PRESSURE);
                    int locationReadingsHumidity = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_HUMIDITY);
                    int locationReadingsWind = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_WIND);
                    int locationReadingsClouds = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_CLOUDS);
                    int locationReadingsVisibility = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_VISIBILITY);
                    int locationReadingsSystolicBP = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_SYSTOLIC_BLOOD_PRESSURE);
                    int locationReadingsDiastolicBP = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_DIASTOLIC_BLOOD_PRESSURE);
                    int locationReadingsHeartRate = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_HEART_RATE);
                    int locationReadingsSPO2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_BLOOD_OXYGEN);
                    int locationReadingsRespirationRate = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_RESPIRATION_RATE);
                    int locationReadingsStatus = cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.READINGS_STATUS);
                    ArrayList<PostReadings> postReadingsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    
                    // GETTING DATA FROM THE CURSOR
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        postReadingsArrayList.add(
                                new PostReadings(
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsID),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsLat),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsLon),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsTimestamp),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsAltitude),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsSpeed),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsBearing),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsAccuracy),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsTemp),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsFeelsLike),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsTempMin),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsTempMax),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsPressure),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsHumidity),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsWind),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsClouds),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsVisibility),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsSystolicBP),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsDiastolicBP),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsHeartRate),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsSPO2),
                                        cursor.getString(locationReadingsRespirationRate),
                                        cursor.getInt(locationReadingsStatus)
                                )
                        );
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                    new DbThread(BackgroundServices.this, postReadingsArrayList, dbHelper).start();
                }
```

Here is DBThread.java

```
public class DbThread extends Thread {
    DBThreadListener listener;
    List<PostReadings> postReadingsList;
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    public DbThread(DBThreadListener listener, List<PostReadings> postReadingsList, DatabaseHelper dbHelper) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
        this.postReadingsList = postReadingsList;
    }

    public void run() {
        listener.updateDB(postReadingsList, dbHelper);
    }

    public interface DBThreadListener {
        void updateDB(List<PostReadings> postReadingsList, DatabaseHelper dbHelper);
    }
}
```

Overriden updateDB in background services

```
@Override
    public void updateDB(List<PostReadings> postReadingsList, DatabaseHelper dbHelper) {
        try {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            Api service = retrofit.create(Api.class);
            for (PostReadings reading : postReadingsList) {
                Call<PostReadingsResponse> readingsCall = service.postAllData(
                        reading.getId(),
                        reading.getLat(),
                        reading.getLon(),
                        reading.getTimestamp(),
                        reading.getAltitude(),
                        reading.getSpeed(),
                        reading.getBearing(),
                        reading.getAccuracy(),
                        reading.getTemp(),
                        reading.getFeelsLike(),
                        reading.getTempMin(),
                        reading.getTempMax(),
                        reading.getPressure(),
                        reading.getHumidity(),
                        reading.getWind(),
                        reading.getClouds(),
                        reading.getVisibility(),
                        reading.getSystolicBP(),
                        reading.getDiastolicBP(),
                        reading.getHeartRate(),
                        reading.getSpo2(),
                        reading.getRespirationRate()
                );

                Response<PostReadingsResponse> response = readingsCall.execute();
                System.out.println("POST_READINGS_RESPONSE" + response.code());
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    PostReadingsResponse postReadingsResponse = response.body();
                    assert postReadingsResponse != null;
                    System.out.println(postReadingsResponse.success);
                    if (postReadingsList.size() > 0) {
                        dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(
                                "UPDATE " + Constants.READINGS_TABLE_NAME + " SET " + Constants.READINGS_STATUS + "=" + Constants.STATUS_UPLOADED +
                                        " WHERE " +
                                        Constants.READINGS_ID + "='" + reading.getId() + "' AND " +
                                        Constants.READINGS_TIMESTAMP + "='" + reading.getTimestamp() + "'");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
```

}

Comment: Use `RxJava` or `AsyncTask (deprecated)` to wrap your `Retrofit` call,

Comment: @SoumikBhattacharjee what difference would that make ? neither of those are synchronous either

Comment: There will be no benefit in using any async task because this service is running with google maps which is already async in behavior. Moreover retrofit call as enqueue is already async in nature while I want this to be as synchronous as the data uploading to server is going different (not in a proper sequence) as in sqlite database